# NullReferenceError when raising an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have a small user control having a textbox and a button in it. I have a label in a page which holds the usercontrol. On a button click event of the user control I want to find out the area of user input value and want to display that area in a label on the main page.

**UserControl**

```
public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   public delegate void myeventhandler(object sender,MyEventArgs e);       

    public event myeventhandler MyEvent;        

     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       int radious= Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
       double area = 3.14 * radious * radious;          
       MyEventArgs myeventargs = new MyEventArgs();
       myeventargs.Area = area;
       MyEvent(this, myeventargs);        

    }        
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public double Area { set; get; }
}
```

**Main page**

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebUserControl1 objuc = new WebUserControl1();           
        objuc.MyEvent += new WebUserControl1.myeventhandler(DisplayArea);              
    }

    public void DisplayArea(object sender,MyEventArgs e) 
    {
         Label1.Text   = e.Area.ToString();               
    }
}
```

But I am getting a NullReferenceError on line

```
MyEvent(this, myeventargs);
```

Comment: It's recommended to tag the question with the programming language you're using as well as any other helpful tag

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide an actual title and a clearer description of your problem

Answer (score 1):

You must check that MyEvent is not null before triggering it.

```
if(null != MyEvent)
    MyEvent(this, myeventargs);
```

Comment: I checked it and  found out that MyEvent is null so getting the NullReferenceError so if Iuse if condition then  MyEvent(this, myeventargs) is not getting call,I want to call it,how to do it??

Comment: It is null because no handler has been attached to the event. Make sure that the button on which you click is the one to which you attached an handler.

Comment: I want to attach the handler in the main page which consuming the UserControl and not in the ButtonClick

Comment: You will need to use a debugger to find out why. Guess: make sure that `Page_Load()` is being called.